# Powershell Oracle DB connection using Encrypted Credentials

Tags: oracle, powershell, odp.net

I was able to get connected to Oracle using the ManagedDataAccess (.net) connection for Oracle, but is there a way to use `OracleCredential` instead of the string password in the connection string?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/odpnt/OracleCredentialClass.html#GUID-193A5715-A785-4CA2-842E-1241DEFD8645